# UITableView - UITableViewCell.Style .subtitle - How to make UIImageView circular? - Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimage, cell

I got a `UITableView` with default cell styles. (set to .subtitle style)
I want to make its `UIImageView` circular.

```
cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.size.width/2
cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

this would not work at this situation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the right way thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50462058/10489699 .

```
        let itemSize = CGSize.init(width: 50, height: 50)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(itemSize, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        let imageRect = CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: itemSize)
        cell.imageView?.image!.draw(in: imageRect)
        cell.imageView?.image! = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = (itemSize.width) / 2
        cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
```

Don't try `if let image = cell.imageView?.image! {...}` , I don't know why but it hits the UIImageView !

Comment: I just upvoted the answer then realised I get some slightly odd behavior the first time you tap an item in the table. The width of the image seems to expand, and then the size seems to incrementally decrease on the cells above (see pic), any ideas? 
![Screenshot](https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/099wpV_QoVT0sfXado6yf7zkw#Screenshot_2022-05-30_at_11.41).

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
public extension UIView {
    func round() {
        let width = bounds.width < bounds.height ? bounds.width : bounds.height
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: bounds.midX - width / 2, y: bounds.midY - width / 2, width: width, height: width)).cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

and you can use like this:

```
profileImageView.round()
```